# Does POSIX make not support globs in prerequisites?

Tags: wildcards, make, posix, portability

I was reading the [POSIX 7 Make definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), and I've noticed that prerequisites are almost always described as “files”:

> The *make* utility examines time relationships and shall update those derived files (called targets) that have modified times earlier than the modified times of the files (called prerequisites) from which they are derived.

Does that mean that a POSIX-compliant make should interpret rules like

```
binary.bin: src/main.c src/1.dir/*.c src/2.dir/*.c
    $(CC) -o binary.bin src/main.c src/1.dir/*.c src/2.dir/*.c
```

As literally looking for files named `*.c` in `src/1.dir/` and `src/2.dir/`?

Does this also mean that, when using a POSIX-compliant make, the users have to enumerate every file in a project in the makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any "lean" implementation of `make` which implements only the features required by the POSIX spec, and which could be used to validate makefiles for POSIX compliance. The POSIX `make` spec is pretty poor, leaving a lot of stuff underspecified, but including dubious and useless features.

FWIW, all Unix make implementations (including GNU make, BSD make, the dmake from solaris, etc) will expand glob patterns in both the target and the prerequisites. And this dates back to the very first implementation of `make` from Unix v7. Quoting from the original [documentation](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/doc/make):

> Other lines give information about target  files.   The general form
>   of an entry is:
>
> ```
> target1 [target2 . . .] :[:] [dependent1 . . .] [; commands] [# . . .]
> [(tab) commands] [# . . .]
>  . . .
> ```
>
> Items  inside  brackets  may be omitted.  Targets and dependents are
>   strings of letters, digits, periods, and  slashes. (**Shell
>   metacharacters `*` and `?` are expanded.**)

And tested in practice:

```
# touch foo.bar zoo.bar

# echo 'foo: *.bar; echo "($?)"' | make -f -
echo "(zoo.bar foo.bar)"
(zoo.bar foo.bar)

# echo 'foo: [zf]oo.bar; echo "($?)"' | make -f -
echo "(zoo.bar foo.bar)"
(zoo.bar foo.bar)
```

Comment: Wikipedia says that the first make was actually from _PWB/UNIX 1,_ which was based on _UNIX V6._ [This make's manpage](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=PWB1/usr/man/man1/make.1) doesn't seem to mention globs, although maybe it does in _Make - A Program for Maintaining Computer Programs,_ which I cannot find. Anyway, thank you for your answer. I guess POSIX simply lacks here.

Comment: that "Make - A Program ..." paper is in the link from my answer (there was a site with all those docs processed into *.pdfs, but I don't remember it). But FWIW, the make from that pwb1 tape is newer than that from v7, and it certainly does globbing. Look at the amatch() function from [files.c](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=PWB1/sys/source/s2/make.d/files.c).

Comment: The source code, duh. Why didn't I think of looking at it? I am extra sloppy today. Thanks again!